# Clone method Sonar issues

Tags: java

If we are implementing a class from `Clonable` then sonar issues get's generated.

SonarQube generates issues for both

1) If clone method is not present then it says implement clone method
2) If we implement clone method with return super.clone() then it says say's use the inherited method.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Overriding a method just to call the same method from the super class without performing any other actions is useless and misleading.

The only time this is justified is in final overriding methods, where the effect is to lock in the parent class behavior. This rule ignores such overrides of equals, hashCode and toString.

Hence you should give proper implementation for override method.

In case of cloning you can implement clone() method in two ways

1- Deep copy

2- Shallow copy

Please refer [Shallow vs. Deep Copy in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/java-copy-shallow-vs-deep-in-which-you-will-swim)

Comment: What if I just want to return super.clone(); I just want to decide JVM to decide which copy has to be sent.

Comment: It does not have any issue, but as per sonarQube(Java language fundamental and its usage) it shows you Code smell, If you want you can avoid it

Comment: I can't avoid it. I need to provide deep cloning. Otherwise I would not be able to clear sonar coverage taget

Comment: One more resource to assist you in deep copy is in this [link](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/)